# service is in a fault state exception only in one environment

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, faultexception, wcf-faults

I am using the same DLLs of various services that I used in one of the development environment to the Test. I ensured configs are same except for endpoint address where it is the servername in each case.

I dont have any problem in Dev. However, in Test, it always says "Service is in faulted state"

1. I tried to point that URL in WCF Test client, I couldn'tt get even to the breakpoint hit as it says service is in fault state. So no dice.
2. I restarted service, recycled app pool creating new one and pointing to the service. No luck
3. Then I researched in net and every article says it could be because of a .net exception. I do not anticipate this exception only in one environment (Not convincing) while the Dev works fine and also local from visual studio and localhost iIs work fine.

I do agree that I don't catch exception in proxy level neither fault or any logging. Its just a simple wrapper but WCF. Considering timelines, I can not add even try catch or fault, as we are baselined.

What could be the issue any idea to debug?

Comment: _"I do not anticipate this exception only in one environment (Not convincing)"_ it's completely plausible - an incorrect config value, permissions, database account access, any number of things could cause the service to fail in the test environment. Add some logging.

Comment: @stuartd: Thank you. Will see. Its strange, connectionstring I verified line by line, all same as Dev. Anyway will look again all of these.

Comment: A bit more info might be required, when a service is in a faulted session, it could mean that your code is throwing an exception instead of a fault.If you havent yet found a solution, I can post something here that might help you better track down the error

Comment: @mahlatse: I didn't find a solution yet